# C# - Array of a class that holds arrays of another class, readable/writable in XML

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, class

My main goal is to create a class (lets call it `test1`) with variables, one of which is an array.
Another class (we'll call this `test2`) will hold other variables, some of which are arrays of the class `test1`.

The size of the arrays are variable and not exactly fixed.  I want to be able to increase/decrease the size of them during run-time.  I also intend for it to be writable and readable to a file, such as XML.  So, from what I understand, it has to be capable of being "serialized".

Would it look something like this?

```
public class test1
{
    public String test1_name;
    public String test1_id;
    public Single test1_value;
    public String[] test1_list;
}

public class test2
{
    public test1[] test2_list1;
    public test1[] test2_list2;
    public String[] test2_list;
}
```

I have managed to figure out how to use XML serialization to write the file, e.g.:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(test_a)); //test_a being a simple class holding a simple variable

var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//tester.txt";
System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);
writer.Serialize(file, tester);
file.Close();
```

I want to ensure that I can write and read this data (either as XML or binary, I will decide later) and have it modifiable during run-time, along with the array sizes being adjustable.

Am I going about this the wrong way?
How would I construct this and have it usable and savable/readable?

Can somebody help put me on the right track for what I want to achieve?
I know it may be a big ask, but some examples would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing fine. Your code already works.

I created this data to test it.

```
var tester = new test2()
{
    test2_list1 = new[]
    {
        new test1()
        {
            test1_name = "11",
            test1_id = "12",
            test1_value = 3.1f,
            test1_list = new string[] { "14", "15", "16", },
        },
        new test1()
        {
            test1_name = "21",
            test1_id = "22",
            test1_value = 3.2f,
            test1_list = new string[] { "24", "25", "26", },
        },
    },
    test2_list2 = new[]
    {
        new test1()
        {
            test1_name = "31",
            test1_id = "32",
            test1_value = 3.3f,
            test1_list = new string[] { "34", "35", "36", },
        },
        new test1()
        {
            test1_name = "41",
            test1_id = "42",
            test1_value = 3.4f,
            test1_list = new string[] { "44", "45", "46", },
        },
    },
    test2_list = new string[] { "X", "Y", "Z", },
};
```

I serialized it using this code:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer
    = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(test2));

var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "//tester.txt";
using (System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path))
{
    serializer.Serialize(file, tester);
    file.Flush();
}
```

I got this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <test2_list1>
    <test1>
      <test1_name>11</test1_name>
      <test1_id>12</test1_id>
      <test1_value>3.1</test1_value>
      <test1_list>
        <string>14</string>
        <string>15</string>
        <string>16</string>
      </test1_list>
    </test1>
    <test1>
      <test1_name>21</test1_name>
      <test1_id>22</test1_id>
      <test1_value>3.2</test1_value>
      <test1_list>
        <string>24</string>
        <string>25</string>
        <string>26</string>
      </test1_list>
    </test1>
  </test2_list1>
  <test2_list2>
    <test1>
      <test1_name>31</test1_name>
      <test1_id>32</test1_id>
      <test1_value>3.3</test1_value>
      <test1_list>
        <string>34</string>
        <string>35</string>
        <string>36</string>
      </test1_list>
    </test1>
    <test1>
      <test1_name>41</test1_name>
      <test1_id>42</test1_id>
      <test1_value>3.4</test1_value>
      <test1_list>
        <string>44</string>
        <string>45</string>
        <string>46</string>
      </test1_list>
    </test1>
  </test2_list2>
  <test2_list>
    <string>X</string>
    <string>Y</string>
    <string>Z</string>
  </test2_list>
</test2>
```

I was able to deserialize using this code:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
    test2 x = (test2)serializer.Deserialize(file);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay with replying.  This is exactly what I was looking for and has filled in the little blanks that I was missing.  You're a star, thanks so much for the detailed response!